# Does the gate leakage current increase or decrease the drain current in MOSFET?

Tags: mosfet, leakage-current, solid-state-devices

I know that the gate leakage means that the electrons are injected from the gate metal into the channel, therefore the conventional current direction is from channel to the gate. From KCL, I think this means that drain current will be decreased due to the current leaking into the gate metal. Is this correct?

Let's say without the gate leakage, the drain current at a certain bias is 1A. Now if we assume that the gate leakage is 0.1A, would the measured drain current by 0.9A?

Comment: It depends whether you have an N or P channel device, and whether the leakage current is in or out, which way the leakage current will be flowing.

Comment: @Neil_UK Thanks. I am assuming n-channel transistor in which the gate current flows from channel to the gate.

Answer (score 1):

It's a current into the D-S path. Whether that should be considered adding to one, or subtracting from the other, depends on what conventions you've made in your analysis.

You'll be hard pressed to measure this in practice as gate leakage is at most some µA, and if you're getting much more than that it's probably been blown the heck out.

Comment: If the convention is that the positive drain current flows from the drain to the source, wouldn't the gate current into the drain-source path increase the net drain current?

Comment: @user207787 Draw the circuit and show your sign conventions.

Answer (score 0):

The direction of leakage current between the gate and channel depends upon the biasing of the MOSFET.

In an N-channel MOSFET, with the MOSFET (fully) *on*, the gate is more positive than both the source and drain. Therefore, in terms of conventional current, any leakage between gate and channel will be from the gate to the channel. With a P-channel MOSFET, this will be reversed.

In an N-channel MOSFET, with the MOSFET *off*, but with a high drain voltage, it is likely that the majority of leakage between the gate and channel will be from the high voltage drain to the lower voltage gate.